# What are the use cases for using either Sverchok or Animation Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, animation-nodes, sverchok

I'm having a hard time digesting all the information inside these two software packages. There are so many options in each one , and some seem to provide the same functionality.

Can someone give a high level overview contrasting the two node frameworks?

When should one be used over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: "*When should one be used over the other?*" They are two competing projects, with a considerable amount of overlapping functionality; use whichever suits your taste best. This question is too broad and open ended, not very fitting for our format here, try https://blenderartists.org/ instead

Comment: I'm a Sverchok developer, you can read [here](http://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/) about our development focus. If none of that relates to your needs you might want to invest time in AN instead.